# Getting a list of papers cited by a given paper in google scholar

Tags: google-scholar

Google scholar does the reverse of what I would like -- it will return a list of papers which cite a given paper.

Is there any way to get a list of all of the papers that a given paper cites, together with links to the papers (if available)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot in Google Scholar. I personally use CiteSeerX to browse easily the references without having to search them one by one, e.g. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.110.7684

Comment: Great, this does more or less what I wanted. Thanks!